# Consistency of estimators in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, linear

Under what conditions are the estimators $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in simple linear regression consistent?

I derived that $S_{xx}$ should go to infinity as n goes to infinity, but I do not get any further.

I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "$S_{xx}$".  I would understand it to be the sum of squares of the regressors, or perhaps the sum of squares of their deviations from their mean.  Either way, it definitely will not go to zero!

Comment: Oops infinity I mean. I changed it in the question. By Sxx I mean the sum of squares of the deviations of the regressors from their mean!

Answer (score 6):

We'll look at $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}$ first.  The law of large numbers says that $\bar{y}$ converges to $\text{E}(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{E}(x)$ and if $\hat{\beta}_1 \to \beta_1$ then $\hat{\beta}_1 \bar{x}$ converges to $\beta_1 \text{E}(x)$.  This means $\hat{\beta}_0$ will be consistent if $\hat{\beta}_1$ is.  Now looking at $\hat{\beta}_1$ and assuming all variances and covariances are finite and well-defined we have

\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_1 &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar{y})(x_i - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
&\to \frac{\text{Cov}(y, x)}{\text{Var}(x)} \\
&= \frac{\text{Cov}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon, x)}{\text{Var}(x)} \\
&= \beta_1 + \frac{\text{Cov}(\epsilon, x)}{\text{Var}(x)}
\end{align}

which equals $\beta_1$ so long as $\text{Cov}(\epsilon, x) = 0$.

To prove the stronger claim that the estimators are consistent in mean square we can start with the variance covariance matrix for $(\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\beta}_1)$ which equals $\sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}$.  Here $X$ is the data matrix and for simple linear regression this is just $[1 ; x]$ where $1$ is a vector of ones and $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is the predictor set.  If we go through the linear algebra we get

$$
(X^T X)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 & - \bar{x} \\ - \bar{x} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 - n \bar{x}^2} 
$$

and the denominator $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 - n \bar{x}^2$ is nothing but the sum of squares for $x$.  This means that as long as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ every element of this matrix goes to zero, including the diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! By consistent, I actually meant that the mean squared error goes to zero, so the variance should go to zero. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: I edited the my post and added some details about the variances.

Comment: @dsaxton: Does your proof work when X is a binary variable (0/1)? More generally, do proofs of consistency of OLS work when some of the design variables are discrete? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they do.  @dsaxton's proof actually shows unbiasedness, which is stronger than consistency; all you really need is that $\lim (X'X)^{-1}/T = Q$, a finite PSD matrix, as $T\to \infty$, and $\mathrm{plim}(X'e/T) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the classic situation in which you assume that the true model is of the form:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + u$, with $E[u] = 0$ . In this case, the OLS estimator will asymptotically converge to $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ provided that $E[xu] = 0$

If you mean consistency in the sense of convergence to the parameters of the best linear approximation to $E[y|x]$, then all you need is that the data you get, $(y_i,x_i)$ is iid.

Comment: Can't we simply require that $E[u | x] = 0,$ since this would imply both $E[u]=0$ and $E[xu] = 0 ?$